# Select previous td and clicking link with Mechanize and Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

Hi I am scrapping a webpage with mechanize and nokogiri. I am selecting a series of links `<a></a>`

```
 html_body = Nokogiri::HTML(body)
    links = html_body.css('.L1').xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a[1]")
```

Then I need to check if the content of each link (`<a>content</a>`, not the `href`) matches some stuff in my db. I am doing this:

```
       links.each do |link|
          if link = @tournament.homologation_number
```

if my condition is realized I need to select the `<td></td>` that is right before the `<td>` of the link I checked and click on the link that's in it.

```
<td><a href="link I want to click if condition is true"></a></td>
<td><a href="">content I check with my condition</a></td>
```

How can I achieve this using Mechanize and nokogiri ?

Answer (score 2):

I would iterate the first `td`'s because it's easier to get at following elements than previous ones (with css anyway)

```
page.search('td[1]').each do |td|
  if td.at('+ td a').text == 'foo'
    page2 = agent.get td.at('a')[:href]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to select all `<td></td>`, the followining xpath `//table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a[1]` only selects the first `<a></a>` element, so you could try something like `//table/tbody/tr/td`, but this depends on the situation.

Once you have your array of `<td></td>` you can access their links like this:

```
tds.each do |td|
  link = td.children.first             # Select the first children
  if condition_is_matched(link.html)   # Only consider the html part of the link, if matched follow the previous link
    previous_td   = td.previous
    previous_url = previous_td.children.first.href
    goto_url previous_url
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok I manage to get the first td but td.previous doesnt catch anything